# Facebook API, not able to fetch first name and profile info

Tags: facebook

From a week we are facing issue with not fetching user profile info from facebook  what may be the setting of the users that it is stopping app from accessing their profile info ( first name and last name ).Just wondering if anybody facing the same and wondering what setting would have created this issue.

1) I have tried changing app setting but profile info was required so couldn't uncheck that option

2) I have tried setting all other  ways privacy but not able to reflect

Error : No error in the console.

And Allows user to login without facebook info information.

If anybody has faced this error and what were the setting/resolution for this issue

Devices: Web App and IOS

Comment: Are you getting an error when making API calls? What is the error message? What does your code for accessing profile info look like? Please [provide more information about the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want people to be able to help.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check

Comment: What API Call are you making?

Comment: Devices both from IOS and web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood where was the issue from , Issue was from IOS app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile

its clearly mention here that for public profile information :

**On the web, public_profile is implied with every request and isn't required, although the best practice is to declare it. On iOS and Android, you must manually request it as part of your login flow.**

So we need explicitly have a call to fetch information while signingup in IOS app.

Answer (score 0):

here is the full example, that you needed just pass `fields=first_name,last_name,email` with `FB.api` request

```
<script>

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', 
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
 };

 (function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));

function facebookAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.login(function(response){
        if (response.authResponse && response.status === 'connected') 
        {
            FB.api('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.first_name+' '+response.last_name);
                console.log(response.first_name);
                console.log(response.last_name);
                console.log(response.email);
            });
        }
      },
      {
        scope: 'email',
        auth_type: 'rerequest'
     });
}
</script>
```

In your html file just call the function `facebookAPI()`  to get the details of any logged facebook user

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="facebookAPI();">CLICK TO FETCH FACEBOOK USER</a>
```